# For sites that allow some types of resource requests, are there any patterns in the rules that allow them?

Tags: discussion

On at least one site (SE) "resource requests" are officially off topic.

On a few others (Programmers, Physics) there can be some resource requests.

Are there any common themes in the ways that those sites that do allow resource requests constrain them, so that they don't end up with crappy, subjective, list-like answers?

Comment: Yes, heavy moderation by all concerned at creating a list that will be obsolete in half a year

Answer (score 2):

There is definitely no concrete set of criteria. I'm not even sure if there's a vaguer pattern. I suppose if a particular request comes up so often that the community decides it's in its best interest to allow some sort of canonical question to exist, then one *might* survive. Sometimes older questions that have been well-maintained are allowed to stick around, too, but there is no real rule to it, it really just comes down to whether or not the community as a whole happens to want a particular question there.

In the rare cases where these questions do exist, in general they are only able to continue to exist because they are under constant watch by various people who regularly work hard to keep the answers up-to-date and comprehensive.

For example, [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list), asked in 2008, which now contains the footer:

> This question's answers are a collaborative effort: if you see something that can be improved, just edit the answer to improve it! *No additional answers can be added here.*

The answers to this question are under continuous watch and are [often edited](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/388282/revisions) to update links and such. Other things are done to clean up those questions as well, for example the one  I just linked to actually has 105 answers, 104 of which were deleted with some being merged into the main one. Even then, with all that effort, it's easy for it to slip out of date, links to die, etc.

Besides the intentionally maintained ones like the example above, sometimes the questions that you see may have just gotten by with nobody noticing them or acting on them for whatever reason. That doesn't necessarily mean they were desired, often it just means they slipped under the radar. These are usually doomed to become obsolete sooner or later.

Really, though, like I said, it just boils down to whether or not the community in general decided that it wanted to allow one of these questions to exist and wanted to continue maintaining it. There isn't really a set of guidelines, and 99.9999% of the time, these questions aren't well-received.